# How to add the third y axis towards the opposite direction (downward) in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want a bar chart with the third y-axis. Two of them go upwards, on the left and right side, respectively. The third one goes downwards. Is it possible in matplotlib?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can create `y1, y3` with `subplots` and `y2` as a `twinx` of `y1`

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True, gridspec_kw={'hspace':0})

# plot something on y1
axes[0].bar([0,1],[2,3],width=-0.4, align='edge')

# y2 and plot something
ax1 = axes[0].twinx()
ax1.bar([0,1],[4,5], width=0.4, align='edge', hatch='o')

# y3 with invert yaxis
axes[1].bar([0,1],[10,15], width=0.4, hatch='//')
axes[1].invert_yaxis()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Cool! It works perfectly. Thank you so much!